# If logged in, My Account/Log Out are missing, how can i fix?

Tags: blocks, users

I have a Drupal Commerce website in development and there is a problem with the User Login  block.

If logged in, it is missing the 'My Account / Log Out' links. But if logged out, is shows the standard links, 'Username/Pass fields, Create New Account, Request New Password' links.

I  have no idea how to fix. can someone please clue me in where to start? This was a PSD to Drupal job so maybe the problem lies in one of the Template files? like Regions.tpl ?

On a standard Drupal install this hasn't been an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user login block doesn't include "My Account" and "Log Out" links.

[`user_block_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_block_view/7) > [`user_login_block`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_block/7)

However, you can add the "User menu" to that region instead

*Admin > Structure > Blocks > "User Menu"*

It contains "My Account" and "Log Out" links.